# How to get the User checked out by info in MS Project

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, ms-project

I am creating a SP workflow which should be triggered on save and first check if the Project Owner field matches the User to whom the Project is Checked out to. On Project center I can see "Checked Out By" field but I can't get to it using the REST call

```
https://pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects(guid'xxx')?$select=CheckedOutby
```

This does not return any response though

Any pointers on how to get the Check Out user in a workflow variable in Sharepoint Designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the CheckedOutBy for an individual project

Endpoint:

```
/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('<guid>')/CheckedOutBy
```

For all Projects at once you can use the below endpoint

```
/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects/?$expand=CheckedOutBy
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked, but I get all the attributes associated with that user, like Login Name, Title, EmailID. So maybe I need to add another step in the workflow - Get d/Title from responseContent

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address this using the Workflow Context - Workflow Associator - return as display name. Since the workflow is triggered on project save event the person who saves the project becomes the workflow associator and i compare that with the Project Data - Owner field and if here is a match i perform subsequent steps else set display on a field as "Workflow initiator is not the project owner"